# Upgrade Magento CE 1.9.2.4 Magento CE 2.3.3 Guide?

Tags: upgrade

We are currently running Magento 1.9.2.4 and would like to upgrade to the latest version of Magento CE 2.3.3. We don't have any custom themes or custom plugins or anything custom. IS there a tool/documentation to perform this upgrade?

We do have access to the database and the ability to install 2.3.3 on another server and do the migration.